# Speed up query on large MySQL table

Tags: mysql, query-performance, where, substring

```
SELECT property, geo, stars     
FROM table
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(geo, '>', 3) LIKE '%$mylocation%'    
...loop to show results
```

geo column has values like - Spain>Canary Islands>Lanzarote>Some Resort

Index set on 'geo' column - Table is MyISAM

Comment: do you realy need to use LIKE '%$mylocation%' here? Wouldn't be enough to find rows LIKE '$mylocation%'?

Comment: In an RDBMS like eg. MySQL, one would normally normalize the data structure.  One column would only contain one attribute.  So you'd have separate columns for eg. country, province, town, etc.  This would speed up your query immensely, as it would allow you to have an index on the columns used as search criteria.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille deoending on actual requirements author may create generated column and index on this column

Comment: Realizing that what I proposed in my comment, wasn't very normalized neither.  The geo column should be the id of the most detailed location, which could be part of a tree structure of broader and broader locations, town -> province -> country.